# Is there a way to easily stub only a given set of methods?

Tags: java, javafx, mockito, java-8, stubbing

I make my first attempt at developing a GUI app (using JavaFX with JDK 8u25 from Oracle) and I want this application tested.

After some trial and error I came up with this basic design which kind of resembles MVP:

- I use FXML;
- the generated "controller" (as JavaFX calls it; it really isn't one to my limited knowledge) only delegates UI events to a "presenter";
- the "presenter" modifies the UI using a "view", which is an interface with a single implementation, and this implementation has access to all GUI elements of the "controller".

As an example, for a `Pane` with "base class name" `Foo`, on an element with id `myButton` which has an action event of `myButtonWasClicked`, the code is as follows:

```
// JavaFX controller
public class FooUi
{
    // Package private on purpose, so that the view can access it
    @FXML
    Button myButton;

    @FXML
    WhateverElement modifiableElement;

    @FXML
    public void myButtonWasClicked(final ActionEvent ignored)
    {
        presenter.processMyButtonWasClicked();
    }
}

// View interface
public interface FooView
{
    void updateSomethingOnGui();
}

// View implementation
public class DefaultFooView
    implements FooView
{
    @Override
    public void updateSomethingOnGui();
    {
        modifiableElemnt.modifyInSomeWay();
    }
}

// Presenter
public class FooPresenter
{
    public void processButtonWasClicked()
    {
        // whatever housekeeping, then
        view.updateSomethingOnGui();
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is with testing... Not that I cannot test it, I can and that's the main point:

```
public final class FooTest
{
    private FooUi ui;
    private FooView view;
    private FooPresenter presenter;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()
    {
        // init ui, view, presenter with Mockito
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyButtonWasClicked()
    {
        final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(presenter, view);

        ui.myButtonWasClicked(mock(ActionEvent.class));

        inOrder.verify(presenter).processMyButtonWasClicked();
        inOrder.verify(view).updateSomethingOnGui();
        inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
    }
}
```

BUT the set of classes to create is rather heavy.

What I'd like to do is to have the `Ui` class implement the `View` class, and that all methods *inherited from the `View` class*, and *only them*, be stubbed, such as in:

```
doNothing().when(ui).updateSomethingOnGui();
```

But I'd like to *not* to have to do this by hand... Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine elements of a unit test and system test in FooTest. Mockito is perfectly suited to test the Presenter as a unit, which interacts only with a well-defined mockable interface. To lightly test that the real pieces fit together well, you may not want to use Mockito at all.

Comment: @JeffBowman I don't really understand what you mean? I could test the presenter alone, yes; do you mean I should test the ui/controller interaction separately? Also, if I don't use mockito, how do I verify that the correct pieces are called?

Comment: Yes, focus on testing separate pieces separately. If possible, test state (e.g. modifiableElement) instead of only interactions (via Mockito), which might be easier to do with integration tests than unit tests here.

Comment: @JeffBowman uhm, the problem with testing such pieces is that it requires an `Application` instance in the correct state; I have had the problem of having an `IllegalStateException` if I didn't mock... And I must admit that I only really know about unit testing!